# VMware ESXi: Create a video of virtual machine

Tags: video, console, esxi

VMware Workstation makes it easy to record videos of virtual machines.  However, my setup is using ESXi - I access the console through vSphere.  I would like to record a video of the virtual machine, but can't seem to find a way to do this through vSphere.  Any ideas?

(Of course, I could just install screen capture software on my own workstation, which is running the console - but I believe I'll get much better results capturing it through vmware itself.  I don't want to install any software on the guest machine.)

Answer (score 2):

vSphere does not feature video recording capability like Workstation I'm afraid..

A screen area/window capture tool on the administrating machine accessing the vSphere client might give better results.

Answer (score 1):

If im not mistaken you can set up VMWare work station to connect to your vShpere server as a client and be able to open your console to be recorded.  Just click on File and then select add server and enter the information for your VSpere vCenter server.